# CumulusCI trailhead challenge stuck due to cci error

Tags: trailhead, cumulusci

I'm new to SF and CumulusCI and I'm learning it through trailhead. I'm currently stuck with the challenge "[Get Ready to Release Your Managed Package](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/cumulusci-for-managed-packages/get-ready-to-release-your-managed-package)" in the "CumulusCI for Managed Packages" module.

The first step of this challenge is to run `cci flow run ci_master --org packaging`, but this fails with the error

```
[Failed]: Update of AppMenu AppSwitcher: Error: In field: AppMenuItem.Name - no ConnectedApp named CPQIntegrationUserApp found
2021-01-31 15:33:26: Exception in task deploy_packaging.deploy

Could not process MDAPI response: Update of AppMenu AppSwitcher: Error: In field: AppMenuItem.Name - no ConnectedApp named CPQIntegrationUserApp found
```

Has someone suggestions on how to handle and fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am a coauthor of CumulusCI and of this Trailhead module*.

Your repository contains some metadata that's not supposed to be there. My best guess is that when you completed [Make and Capture Customizations to Your App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/community-project-development-with-cumulusci/make-and-capture-customizations-to-your-app?trail_id=build-applications-with-cumulusci), you may have been working with an org that wasn't a scratch org - perhaps another Trailhead Playground or a persistent org that contained CPQ.

You can probably recover from this issue by simply deleting metadata from your repository that doesn't belong there. At this point on the Trail, you should have only Custom Objects, and possibly Page Layouts and Profiles, in your repository. If you have AppMenu metadata, go ahead and remove it.

If you need more help or can help us understand how you got stuck in this position, please visit the [CumulusCI](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009M9Z) group on the Trailblazer Community where we can do more iterative debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much. Removing `applications` and `appMenus` metadata solved it.